# How to make dictionary entry from third word of each line in a file

Tags: python, dictionary, key, key-value

I have a text file :

```
hey student1 aaa 123 yes
hi student2 bbb 321 yes
hello student3 aaa 432 no
hi student4 bbb 589 yes
```

I want to use dictionary data structure in python to group all lines with aaa together and send to a file called aaa_file and do the same thing with bbb.

code i tried:

```
import json
import sys

with open("text.txt", 'r') as f:
   lines = f.readlines

newDict{}

for line in lines    
    unit = line.split()    
    newDict[unit[2]]=unit[0:]
print(json.dumps(newDict, indent = 4))
```

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will help you with that

```
import json
import sys
from collections import defaultdict

with open("text.txt", 'r') as f:
   lines = f.readlines()[1:]

newDict = defaultdict(list)

for line in lines:
    print(line)
    unit = line.split(" ")
    newDict[unit[2]].append(unit)
print(json.dumps(newDict, indent = 4))
for key in newDict:    
    with open("{}_list.json".format(key), "w") as f:
        for i in newDict[key]:
            f.write(" ".join(i) + "\n")
```

Output

```
   {
    "aaa": [
        [
            "hey",
            "student1",
            "aaa",
            "123",
            "yes"
        ],
        [
            "hello",
            "student3",
            "aaa",
            "432",
            "no"
        ]
    ],
    "bbb": [
        [
            "hi",
            "student2",
            "bbb",
            "321",
            "yes"
        ],
        [
            "hi",
            "student4",
            "bbb",
            "589",
            "yes"
        ]
    ]
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215864/discussion-on-answer-by-leo-arad-how-to-make-dictionary-entry-from-third-word-of).